# Checking username availability with ajax using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I try to use the next example to checking username availability but I can't receive the result of .post that I want.

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/

In the next code, the alert() show me the .php file, but I just want 0 or 1 in order to know if the user exist or not:

```
    //use ajax to run the check
    $.post("check_username.php", { username: username },
        function(result){ alert(result);
            //if the result is 1
            if(result == 1){
                //show that the username is available
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is Available');
            }else{
                //show that the username is NOT available
                $('#username_availability_result').html(username + ' is not Available');
            }
    });
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does the alert say?

Comment: It shows the .php file, all the code in the alert() window.

Comment: after  var username = $('#username').val();  alert(username) and check what is the value you are sending. Also what is the alert you get after the post ?

Comment: alert(username) show the user of the <input type='text' id='username'>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are you hosting your php file? Inside apache? If you are getting the full contents of php file then most probably you have not deployed it correctly.

Comment: I'm using in localhost a WampServer. What is your advice? :)

Comment: Try to call the php file using your browser's address and see what is being returned. For example http://localhost/MYAPPNAME/check_username.php if you are still getting contents of the file then it is really a server issue.

Comment: @Shamaila Tahir I didn't put the file in the good place for apache. Now I have a sql error, thanks, I try to fix it.